# Ffmpeg image overlay causes video to freeze

Tags: php, command-line, ffmpeg

I made a php script that generates a ffmpeg command line that generates a movie with fades. When I add an image over the video the first scene freezes after about 3 seconds for less than a second, everything works fine after.

When I don't add the image everything works fine. When I execute the command line in the browser everything works, but when I execute it in the command line with a png image an error occurs, jpg image doesn't show an error but the 1 second freeze is still there.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ffmpeg>ffmpeg -y -i 60SecondCountdown.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=0:duration=8.667,afifo[a0];[0:v]trim=0:duration=6.667,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:v]trim=6.667:duration=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:alpha=1[0fo];[0:a]atrim=10:duration=8.667,afifo[a1];[0:v]trim=11:duration=5.667,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:v]trim=10:duration=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:alpha=1[0fi];[0:v]trim=16.667:duration=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=pix_fmts=yu
va420p,fade=t=out:alpha=1[1fo];[0:a]atrim=21:duration=6.666,afifo[a2];[0:v]trim=22:duration=5.666,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:v]trim=21:duration=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:alpha=1[1fi];[0fi]fifo[0fififo];[0fo]fifo[0fofifo];[1fi]fifo
[1fififo];[1fo]fifo[1fofifo];[0fofifo][0fififo]overlay[0f];[1fofifo][1fififo]overlay[1f];[v0][0f][v1][1f][v2]concat=n=5[output];[a0][a1]acrossfade=d=2[audio];[output]scale=320:-1[output];[output][1:v]overlay=W-w-20:H-h-20[output];[audio][a2]acrossfade=d=2[audio
]" -map [output] -map [audio] 2>&1 -strict -2 preview/20190411092942.mp4
ffmpeg version N-77715-gfc703f5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --en
able-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --en
able-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --
enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavcodec     57. 21.100 / 57. 21.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '60SecondCountdown.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-08-28 07:24:49
  Duration: 00:01:05.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 994 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x676 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:169], 864 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-28 07:24:49
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-28 07:24:49
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
[png @ 0000022d8a48e1e0] Invalid PNG signature 0x10001002828.
[image2 @ 0000022d8a4ade20] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 0000022d8a4ade20] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
image.png: could not find codec parameters
Input #1, image2, from 'image.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1036 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, none(pc), 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[buffer @ 0000022d8a513a00] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0000022d8a513a00] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
[buffer @ 0000022d8a513a00] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0000022d8a513a00] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0000022d8a55bf20] Error applying options to the filter.
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: "an error occurs" – what error is it? Please show the full uncut log.

Comment: I only get this error when I add the image, [buffer @ 000002736ebb14e0] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 000002736ebb14e0] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
[buffer @ 000002736ebb14e0] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 000002736ebb14e0] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 000002736ebfab60] Error applying options to the filter.
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Please show the **full, uncut** log. You can [edit] your question to add it. Also, when you say, "when I don't add the image", that command doesn't work, right? And when you say you execute it "in the browser" what does that mean? The command is executed by PHP. If you do that, then it works, and if you copy the *exact same* command to a shell, it does not? If that is true, please show the respective logs from both of these runs.

Comment: My code generated the command line so when I dont add the image it just doesn't add the image to the overlay. And if I execute it with php there are no errors and the video gets generated with the 1 second delay and when I copy the exact same command line to shell it shows the error.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that `image.png` is actually a PNG file? Please share a link to `image.png`. 2. Your `ffmpeg` is old. You should [upgrade](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) before doing anything else.

Comment: I used a different image.png and this one gives no error, the 1 second freeze is still there though. I used [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) image for testing

Comment: I have exactly same problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429047/ffmpeg-when-use-overlay-output-have-delay

Comment: I have already found the solution to this problem. I kept getting an error in the console that said 'buffer queue overflow'. I found out that this error could be fixed by using a fifo filter. this is how the part I changed looks like:
`[0:v]trim=120:duration=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fifo[v1];`